# attempt to insert nil object from objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I have this below error

> -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1539]

It happens sometimes I try to tap several times on  screen, because code is little, so all the code is pasted below

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * testArray;
@property (nonatomic,strong) dispatch_queue_t queue1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) dispatch_queue_t queue2;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.testArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    _queue1 = dispatch_queue_create("test", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    _queue2 = dispatch_queue_create("test",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(addObjectforArray) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       dispatch_async(_queue2, ^{
           NSLog(@"touchesBeganThread:%@",[NSThread currentThread]);
           NSArray * testTempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.testArray];
           for (UIView *view in testTempArray) {
               NSLog(@"%@",view);
           }

    });
}

- (void)addObjectforArray{
    dispatch_async(_queue1, ^{
        NSLog(@"addObjectThread:%@",[NSThread currentThread]);
        [self.testArray addObject:[[UIView alloc]init]];
    });
}
```

I can not understand why this happens, if I change **_queue1 to DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL**, it becomes normal.

How can I understand this issue? If anyone could shed some light, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code. They can cause all sorts of bugs randomly.

1. `UIView` should be created in the main thread using `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit

   > For the most part, use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread or main dispatch queue. This restriction applies to classes derived from 
   >   UIResponder
   >   or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.
2. The property `testArray` is `nonatomic` but being accessed in two threads. The property should be `atomic`. It runs fine at this moment but it is fragile. If in the future `testArray` mutates, the app will crash randomly.
3. `NSArray` is not thread-safe. It should be locked while accessing in multiple threads or protected by other means.
4. As pointed out by @Nirmalsinh, the `dispatch_async` is redundant (actually harmful).

I am not sure if you have heavily simplified your code or only to test something. If you are not doing long running work, you might want to use `dispatch_get_main_queue()` in `dispatch_async`. It will save you from a lot of troubles.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are inserting nil value into your array. You cannot add nil to array or dictionary.

```
- (void)addObjectforArray{
        NSLog(@"addObjectThread:%@",[NSThread currentThread]);
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        if(view != nil)
            [self.testArray addObject:view];
}
```

There is no required to use a queue in the method. You are already using NSTimer for same.

Try to check above. It will help you.

Comment: `-[UIView init]` will never return `nil`.

Comment: You need to alloc it. [[UIView alloc]init]